# how to override stdin with /dev/tty?

Tags: stdin, crystal-lang

I'm writing a git pre-commit hook, but it requires user input and hooks don't run in an interactive terminal. With Python I could do something like this to get access to user input:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

# This is required because git hooks are run in non-interactive
# mode. You aren't technically supposed to have access to stdin.
# This hack works on MaxOS and Linux. Mileage may vary on Windows.
sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty')

result = input("Gimme some input: ")
```

What is the appropriate way to do this in Crystal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by combining @julian-portalier's answer and @asterite's we have  working way to redefine stdin:

```
STDIN.reopen(File.open("/dev/tty", "a+"))
```

Which, I believe, is just [FileDescriptor#reopen](http://crystal-lang.org/api/IO/FileDescriptor.html#reopen)

`STDIN`, `STDOUT`, and `STDERR` can all be reopened this way.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
STDIN.reopen("/dev/tty")
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
file = File.open("/dev/tty")
line = file.gets
p line
```

You can't reassign STDIN and we don't have a reassignable global variable for it. I don't know much about this, maybe reopen and dup can be used for that. But otherwise you can use that `file` instead of `STDIN` in your program, I guess.

Comment: thanks to your answer and the other one i figured out how to reassign STDIN. see my answer.